# Pass Plot to Function Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I was hoping to create a function that will set the x axis limit for a plot. Here is what is **working** currently:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def scatter_plot(df, user_conditions):
    data_to_plot = user_conditions['data_to_plot']
    title = data_to_plot.replace("_", " ").title()
    df1 = df[['time',data_to_plot]]
    df1 = index_dataframe_time(df1)
    plt.scatter(df1.index.to_pydatetime(), df1[data_to_plot])
    min = df1.index.min()
    max = df1.index.max()
    plt.xlim(min, max)
    plt.title('Hour of Day vs '+title, fontsize=14)
    plt.show()
```

Here is what I was hoping for:

```
def scatter_plot(df, user_conditions):
    data_to_plot = user_conditions['data_to_plot']
    title = data_to_plot.replace("_", " ").title()
    print title
    df1 = df[['time',data_to_plot]]
    df1 = index_dataframe_time(df1)
    plot = plt.scatter(df1.index.to_pydatetime(), df1[data_to_plot])
    plot = set_limits(df1, plot)
    plot.title('Hour of Day vs '+title, fontsize=14)
    plot.show()

def set_limits(df, plot):
    min = df.index.min()
    max = df.index.max()
    plot.xlim(min, max)
    return plot
```

However, there is an issue in `set_limits` with `plot.xlim(min,max)`,

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
File
> "C:/Users/Application/main.py", line 115, in <module>
>     
main()   
> 
> File "C:/Users/Application/main.py", line
> 106,
> in main
>     plot_configuration(df, user_conditions)   File "C:/Users/Application/main.py", line 111,
> in plot_configuration
>     scatter_plot(df, user_conditions)   
File "C:/Users/Application/main.py", line 76,
> in scatter_plot
>     plot = set_limits(df1, plot)   File "C:/Users/Application/main.py", line 83,
> in set_limits
>     plot.xlim(min, max) AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'xlim'
```

How can set_limits be modified in order to fix this?

Comment: How did you import `matplotlib`?  e.g. where does `plt` come from?

Comment: @mgilson Sorry about that, question is now fixed to reflect that

Comment: The problem is that `pyplot` is a stateful module which is meant to be convenient for people who are used to matlab.  In particular, the statefulness is why `plt.set_xlim` works -- `pyplot` has a reference to the figure (and axes) that you're currently working with.  If you want to work with the plots themselves, this doesn't work (well) and you'll need to use the object oriented interface provided by `matplotlib.figure`.  [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5450333/748858).  I suppose you _could_ use `pyplot.gcf()` to get the current figure ...

Comment: The problem is that the object passed into the `set_limits` function as written as used is the `Collection` artist returned by scatter which does not have any notion of limits.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to be doing something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def scatter_plot(ax, df, user_conditions):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : matplotlib.axes.Axes
        The axes to put the data on
    df : pd.DataFrame
        The data
    user_conditions : dict (?)
        bucket of user input to control plotting?
    """
    data_to_plot = user_conditions['data_to_plot']
    title = data_to_plot.replace("_", " ").title()
    print(title)
    df1 = df[['time',data_to_plot]]
    df1 = index_dataframe_time(df1)
    # sc = ax.scatter(df1.index.to_pydatetime(), df1[data_to_plot])
    # only works in 1.5.0+
    sc = ax.scatter(df1.index.to_pydatetime(), data_to_plot,
                    data=df)
    set_limits(df1, ax)
    ax.set_title('Hour of Day vs '+title, fontsize=14)

    return sc

def set_limits(df, ax):
    min = df.index.min()
    max = df.index.max()
    ax.set_xlim(min, max)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
arts = scatter_plot(ax, df, user_conditions)
```

if you are not varying the size or color of the markers you are better off using `ax.plot(..., linestile='none', marker='o')` which will render faster.  In this case something like (if you have 1.5.0+)

```
ax.plot(data_to_plot, linestyle='none', marker='o', data=df)
```

and it should 'do the right thing'.